# Gstreamer : Fast Rewind of Video File

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to rewind a video file with "-1" rate parameter.
It rewinds for a small duration and then the playback stops. Finally the player gets killed.
However the fast forward for the same video file works fine. I tested it with "2x" and "4x" speed. If I just seek backwards with certain duration (rate is "1.0" ), it goes to that timestamp and starts the playback as expected.

From what I understand, Seek event is handled in the Demuxer element of the pipeline, wherein:

1. It flushes the currently queued stream data
2. Creates a new-segment with updated values from the seek event.
3. Once the new segment is ready with the new stream data, playback starts.
   From here on playback will be started,based on the new parameters set in new segment.

For the reverse playback, I'm not able to figure out where the pipeline is actually getting blocked.
I'm able to see the demuxer element is fetching the data and pushing it on the new segment.
Can anyone suggest or point where the issue could be?

Answer (score 2):

Reverse playback might not be properly implemented here. Please file a bug, give as much details about the format (e.g. using gst-discoverer) and if possible link to the file.

Comment: The format i tried this on was MKV.The rewind works in certain cases depending upon the seek flag which I would use while sending the seek event.
For Ex:if I use GstSeekFlags::GST_SEEK_FLAG_KEY_UNIT or GST_SEEK_FLAG_NONE the rewind works( with NO visible keyframe update on display.However play duration gets updated with backward values and when play resumes it starts playing from the actual position after rewind.)
The rewind fails if I use GstSeekFlags::GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH
Can you please suggest me where I need to look in,so that atleast i can get the keyframes displayed during rewind?

Comment: For scrubbing (or any case where you send lot of seek events) _KEY_UNIT is a good ideas as if won't wast time do decode and throw away frames to get to exact positions. Flush would simple drain the pipeline, which is not needed, when changing the speed.